# How to add drag-and-drop elements to frontend?

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of creating a Django webapp and one of the apps requires the order of elements on the page to be rearranged by the owner of the content dynamically.

I've been looking into this and haven't really found a solution that would work with Django. So far, I think using a table might be the best way of doing this, but I'm not sure about how to implement it.

I was looking at http://tabulator.info/ which has a drag and drop sortable table that might work, but again, not sure how to go about integrating it with Django.

I know it's easy to implement drag and drop elements into HTML, but what I need is for the moved elements to SAVE so that when the user comes back to the page, they're in the order they were left at.

Any help or links would really be appreciated!

Comment: If it's frontend, this isn't actually anything to do with django. You need a javascript approach to do this. https://shopify.github.io/draggable/

Comment: Would using something like that save the order for the user and not just go back to the original order when they close the page?

Comment: Well that depends how the javascript interacts with the backend doesn't it? Maybe take a look at this package focused on admin, but could be adapted/used for your purposes; https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2

Comment: I looked over the one you linked and I'd seen it before, but I can't see how it might be adapted. I don't know Javascript very well so I don't have much of an idea of how to connect it to a database to save, which is why I'm reaching out here.